# Java Display Error

Tags: java

```
private int []arr;
private int size;
private static int counter;

public binary_search(int val){
    size = val;
    counter = 0;
    arr = new int[size];
}
public boolean isFull(){
    if(counter>=size)
        return true;
    return false;
}
public void add_element(int element){
    if(!isFull()){
        arr[counter] = element;
        for(int j=0;j<counter;j++)
        System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Full Array");
    }
    counter ++;
}
```

In this piece of code I am experiencing difficulty printing the value of array it always gives the previous value..

For example
1)if i insert 5 displays nothing..
2)but after this if I insert 7 it will display  5

Answer (score 0):

This is because your loop terminates before its first iteration:

`for(int j=0;j<counter;j++)`

When `counter` is 0, `j == counter`, so the condition fails.

Instead try:

```
for(int j=0;j<=counter;j++){
    System.out.println(arr[j]);
}
```